# How to check the size of an external pointer's target in R

Tags: r

Consider this demo

```
# R Session shows 118 MB memory usage in Activity Monitor

# Load xgboost
library(xgboost)

# Build matrix
myMatrix <- matrix(data = sample(10 * 10^8, replace = T), ncol = 10)
object.size(myMatrix)   # 4000000216 bytes

# R Session shows 7.69 GB memory usage in Activity Monitor

# Build xgb.DMatrix
myDMatrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = myMatrix)
object.size(myDMatrix)  # 472 bytes

# R Session shows 15.88 GB memory usage in Activity Monitor
```

Here, I

1. Make a big matrix
2. Make an xgb.DMatrix from my big matrix.

From my understanding `xgb.DMatrix(data = myMatrix)` basically creates a copy of `myMatrix` somewhere in memory and retains a pointer to that copy. However, R only has access to the pointer, so my R environment gives the illusion that the xgb.DMatrix is small.

I can use mac's Activity Monitor to see that a big chunk of memory is getting allocated to my R Session when I call `xgb.DMatrix(data = myMatrix)`.

My question is, from R, how I can check the size of the object created by `xgb.DMatrix(data = myMatrix)`, i.e. the thing that `myDMatrix` is pointing to?

Comment: Hey Ben, any chance you figured this out?